# how to clear authentication cache on ie7 with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

We need to clear the authentication cache in IE with Javascript. On IE6 we use: `document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache');` and it works. On IE7 it doesnt work.

what can i do? thanks...

Answer (score 6):

Are you seeing any JavaScript errors (a yellow exclamation mark icon in the lower left corner)? Can you provide more details? Are you *absolutely* certain that line of code is executing (try adding `alert('execCommand');` above and below it). It is possible some other JavaScript error caused by something that works in Internet Explorer 6 but does not work in Internet Explorer 7 is preventing that line of code from executing.

According to the [IDM_CLEARAUTHENTICATIONCACHE Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536979.aspx) documentation it works in Internet Explorer 6 SP1 and above.

I just tried `document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache')` in Internet Explorer 7 and 8 and it worked in both. I didn't even have it in my page source.

1. I went to a page requiring authentication.
2. I logged in.
3. I navigated away from that page, then back again, I did not have to re-authenticate.
4. I then pasted `javascript:void(document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache'));` into the address bar.
5. I navigated away from the page and back again and I had to re-authenticate.

Can you verify that the above steps are not working for you?

Do you have a page where this problem is occurring that we could use for testing?

Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1205045/edit) with any other information you can provide. Thanks.