# How to clear WinInet SSL state programmatically (is there a Windows API call)?

Tags: windows, delphi, ssl, wininet

I need to mimic the same behavior as the "Clear SSL State" button in the "Internet Options" dialog ("Contents" tab) using an API function in Delphi.

My intention is to use this with WinInet to make subsequent independent SSL connections. Without this, two WinInet connections share the same SSL state, preventing me from correcting a wrong SSL certificate password, for example.

Without clearing the SSL state between two connection attempts, the first one returns "wrong password", then I correct the password and try again, but the second attempt returns "Secure Channel Support Error".

Comment: To those are voting to close my question, read it carefully. It is a simple question like any other out there here at Stack Overflow. It is not off-topic. I need to know how to, programmaticaly, execute the very same behaviour of the mentioned button, because I could not find any useful reference about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally! I achieved!

I used the excellent [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor), to monitor the whole Internet Options dialog and I managed to discover what the "Clear SSL State" button do. It executes only two API calls *SslEmptyCache* and *IncrementUrlCacheHeaderData*, in that order.

[image: API Monitor Showing the two API calls beneath the Clear SSL State Button]

After discover this I was able to implement the following code, executed BEFORE my request:

```
type
    TSslEmptyCache = function (pszTargetName: LPSTR; dwFlags: DWORD): BOOL; WINAPI;
    TIncrementUrlCacheHeaderData = function (nIdx: DWORD; lpdwData: LPDWORD): BOOL; WINAPI;

var
    SchannelDLLHandle, WinInetHandle: HMODULE;
    SslEmptyCache: TSslEmptyCache;
    IncrementUrlCacheHeaderData: TIncrementUrlCacheHeaderData;

SchannelDLLHandle := LoadLibrary('schannel.dll');
WinInetHandle := LoadLibrary('wininet.dll');

if (SchannelDLLHandle > 0) and (WinInetHandle > 0) then
    try
        SslEmptyCache := GetProcAddress(SchannelDLLHandle,'SslEmptyCacheW');
        IncrementUrlCacheHeaderData := GetProcAddress(WinInetHandle,'IncrementUrlCacheHeaderData');

        if Assigned(SslEmptyCache) and Assigned(IncrementUrlCacheHeaderData) then
        begin
            SslEmptyCache(nil,0);
            IncrementUrlCacheHeaderData(14,@buffer);
        end;
    finally
        FreeLibrary(SchannelDLLHandle);
        FreeLibrary(WinInetHandle);
    end;
```

Of course, this is a pseudo code, but It is complete ;)

The SslEmptyCache function has documentation at MSDN, but the IncrementUrlCacheHeaderData function not, so I had to research a little more to discover that the second paramenter must be a PDWORD, wich receives, when the function returns, an increment number, wich is persistent between calls at different processes (different applications).

For more information you can access [this article](http://www.zettaomnis.net.br/portal/zost-mei/articles-zost-mei/149-o-limite-da-persistencia-ao-buscar-uma-solucao.html) where I explain all my saga. The text is in portuguese, but the site have a good translatin tool.

I wish to thank you all for the help

Comment: Upvote for the research, and for the link to API Monitor!

Answer (score 1):

The "Clear SSL State" button simply executes the following undocumented command-line command:

```
"C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" "C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll",DispatchAPICall 3
```

Use `CreateProcess()` to execute the same command in your Delphi code.

Comment: Hello, I saw this approach out there, but I really need a true API call to achieve this. Is there a way to call DispatchAPICall directly? I do not found any documentation about it

Comment: @CarlosFeitozaFilho "*I really need a true API call to achieve this*" - there isn't one. "*Is there a way to call DispatchAPICall directly?*" - sure, simply [call it the same way rundll32.exe does](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/164787/info-windows-rundll-and-rundll32-interface).

Comment: It doesn't work only when you call `DispatchAPICall()` directly? Or it doesn't work at all, even when you call it via rundll32? If it works in rundll32, but not in your Delphi code, then your code is not calling it correctly.

Comment: None of them worked :/ The same initial behavior continues. I'm having some ideas here. If they work I'll share with you

Comment: Is it the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205045/how-to-clear-authentication-cache-on-ie7-with-javascript)? Then perhaps it'll work with a TWebBrowser instance's `execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache')`

Comment: @StijnSanders Do you know how to execute the "ClearAuthenticationCache" programatically? Or, which are the real API functions beneath it? The *execCommand* command seems to be useable only on JavasCript and I need something tu use inside Delphi

Comment: This works for me: add a TWebBrowser instance on a form: 
`uses MSHTML;
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:blank');
  (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache',true,EmptyParam);
end;`

Comment: @StijnSanders That's the problem, I do not use TWebBrowser and I do not want to use it. I want to use pure API calls to achieve and fortunately I got it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're right: if rundll can do it, you can do it programmatically:

```
//somewhere in an interface section:
procedure DispatchAPICall(h: HWND; hinst: HINST; lpszCmdLine: PAnsiChar; nCmdShow: integer); stdcall;

//somewhere in the implementation section:
function DispatchAPICall; external 'wininet.dll';

//somewhere in your code:
DispatchAPICall(GetDesktopWindow(), GetModuleHandle('wininet.dll'), '3', SW_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Sorry, but unfortunately I used exactly this same code. I actually copied / pasted your code and even then the SSL State was not cleared. +1 for this answer because you was strict to my request ("Windows API Call"). Thank you!

Comment: The declaration of `DispatchAPICall()` is wrong. Per the [rundll32 documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/164787/info-windows-rundll-and-rundll32-interface), it needs to be a `procedure` not a `function`, and `lpszCmdLine` needs to be a `PAnsiChar` not a `PChar` (which is `PWideChar` in D2009+), eg: `procedure DispatchAPICall(hwnd: HWND; hinst: HINST; lpszCmdLine: PAnsiChar; nCmdShow: Integer); stdcall;` Also, the `hinst` needs to be the `HINST` of the DLL, not the EXE. Since you are linking statically, you can use `GetModuleHandle('wininet.dll')` to that handle.

Comment: The `HINSTANCE` of the specific DLL? Should you get that with `LoadLibrary` or `GetModuleHandle` since the process start will have loaded it for you?

Comment: @StijnSanders: Yes, the `HINSTANCE` of the loaded DLL you are calling into. If you dynamically load the DLL yourself, use the handle that `LoadLibrary()` returns. If you statically link to the DLL, use the handle that `GetModuleHandle()` returns.

Comment: Thanks for the information guys! But, if I'm using the full command on the Run dialog (rundll32.exe) and it's not working, I guess import this DLL wil not work at all, right?

Comment: Well I decided to test the approach one more time, because previously I used the static loading. Now I've done dynamic loading:

  `h := LoadLibrary('wininet.dll');
  DispatchAPICall := GetProcAddress(h,'DispatchAPICall');
  DispatchAPICall(GetDesktopWindow,h,'3',SW_NORMAL);`

The result is the same. This command do not really clear the SSL State. I found this solution before ask here on Stack Overflow on very old sites, so, I guess, this is not working anymore. I've tested on Windows 7 and Windows 10

Comment: The signature used was:

`TDispatchAPICall = procedure (hwnd: HWND; hinst: HINST; lpszCmdLine: PAnsiChar; nCmdShow: Integer); stdcall;`

and `h: TDispatchAPICall`